# Terminology: absolute/unconditional/uncountable additivity

Tags: probability-theory, terminology

Let $\{E_i\}_{i\in I}$ be a family of disjoint events. The principle of countable additivity says that if $I$ is countable, then
$$P\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}E_i\right) = \sum_{i\in I}P(E_i).$$
What if we remove the restriction that $I$ be countable, and consider the principle that this holds for $I$ of any cardinality? Is there a generally accepted term for that principle?

Comment: Such a sum cannot converge if more than countably many of the terms are zero, thus such sums generally don't come up.  More generally, a sum over a set is integration over that set with respect to counting measure.  If your index set is uncountable, then you lose $\sigma$-finiteness of the underlying $\sigma$-algebra, which is, generally speaking, undesirable.

Comment: @Xander: You mean "if more than countably many of the terms are *different from* zero", right? Assuming that: The left-hand side can only be equal to the right-hand side if the right-hand side is well-defined, so it is a necessary condition for the satisfaction of the principle that only countably many of the terms are different from zero (at least that is what I intended with the formulation).

Comment: NONzero!  NONzero!  Yes.  That is what I meant.

Comment: The problem is that the unit interval is the disjoint union of uncountably many singleton sets, each of measure zero. But the unit interval has measure one. You can't square that circle. You have to avoid it by limiting yourself to countable additivity.

Comment: I'm merely asking a question about terminology. Even stupid principles can have names.

Comment: I believe that's called a *discrete* probability distribution.

Comment: @bof Certainly not.

Comment: @Did Thank you for the correction. I thought that the condition $P(E)=\sum_{x\in E}P(\{x\}$ characterized discrete probability distributions. In what way have I erred? Is the condition insufficient, or is it unnecessary, or does it fail on both counts?

Comment: @bof This is simply not what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @Did I don't understand. Is $$P\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}E_i\right) = \sum_{i\in I}P(E_i)\text{ for disjoint sets }E_i$$ not equivalent to $$P(E)=\sum_{x\in E}P(\{x\})?$$ What am I missing?

Comment: @bof ?? The question asks about a generalization of countable additivity to the additivity **for uncountable families**. No such generalization is called "a discrete probability distribution." If you think otherwise, please explain.

Comment: @Did In a discrete probability space, $$P\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}E_i\right) = \sum_{i\in I}P(E_i)$$ holds for disjoint events with no cardinality restriction on the index set. (Needless to say, since they are disjoint, all but countably many of the $E_i$ will be empty.)

Comment: @bof Again, this is quite unrelated (and not even specific to discrete probability spaces).

Answer (score 0):

"Perfect additivity" according to Bruno de Finetti (1972) "Probability, Induction and Statistics", Wiley.